# How to center two views using view.frame and view.center

Tags: ios, animation

I am trying to do something pretty basic here. I am using a block-based UIView animation to bring the subview that is currently off the screen to the current view's center. Obviously the `sp.view.frame = self.view.center` line is the issue here. In the end, how do I do what I want?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
    sp.view.frame = self.view.center;        
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, `sp.view.frame` returns a `CGRect` whereas `self.view.center` returns a `CGPoint`. The two are not the same type and so one cannot be set to the other. ASssuming you wish to set the center of `sp.view` to be the center of `self.view`, you can do that in one of two ways:

```
sp.view.center = self.view.center;
```

or

```
[sp.view setCenter:self.view.center];
```

Comment: so there is no way to set a subview to the current view's center?
I don't necessarily need to use .frame

Comment: This is wrong, as Noah points out in other answer "A subview’s center will not be in the same coordinate system as its superview. Setting one’s center to the other’s is meaningless"

Answer (score 9):

```
self.view.center
```

is a CGPoint struct.

```
sp.view.frame
```

is a CGRect struct.

You can't assign a CGPoint to a CGRect, as the types are not the same.

If you want to center a subview, use something like this, assuming `sp.view` is a subview of `self.view`:

```
sp.view.frame = CGRectMake
(
    ( self.view.frame.size.width  / ( CGFloat )2 ) - ( sp.view.frame.size.width  / ( CGFloat )2 ),
    ( self.view.frame.size.height / ( CGFloat )2 ) - ( sp.view.frame.size.height / ( CGFloat )2 ),
    sp.view.frame.size.width,
    sp.view.frame.size.height
);
```

**EDIT**

Or as Noah suggested:

```
sp.view.center = CGPointMake( self.view.bounds.size.width / 2, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2);
```

Thanks Noah, btw...

Comment: A subview’s center will not be in the same coordinate system as its superview. Setting one’s center to the other’s is meaningless.

Comment: What if I do not know the index? Can I use a variable pointing to the subview?
And @Noah, the subview is full screen but some of it is transparent so thats why I want to do this.

Comment: Closer, but still off. That’ll place the subview’s top-left corner at the center of its superview. Probably best just to use `subview.center = CGPointMake(superview.bounds.size.width / 2, superview.bounds.size.height / 2)`

Comment: You should also floor your values, or use CGRectIntegral to avoid sub-pixel rendering.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add a macro like this
`#define countmid(X,Y) (float) (X-Y)/2`
and then use it in code as
`float Center = countmid(VIEW.frame.size.width,SUB.frame.size.width);`
to place your SUB view at horizontal center of VIEW
The same for Vertical center, just use height against width

Comment: You need to be really careful how you define macros in C.  This one should be #define COUNTMID(X,Y) ((float)((X)-(Y))/2)